# How to properly implement Optimistic Locking at the application layer?

Tags: java, mysql

I am a little confused as to why Optimistic Locking is actually safe. If I am checking the version at the time of retrieval with the version at the time of update, it seems like I can still have two requests enter the update block if the OS issues an interrupt and swaps the processes before the commit actually occurs. For example:

```
latestVersion = vehicle.getVersion();
if (vehicle.getVersion() == latestVersion) {
    // update record in database
} else {
    // don't update record 
}
```

In this example, I am trying to manually use Optimistic Locking in a Java application without using JPA / Hibernate. However, it seems like two requests can enter the `if` block at the same time. Can you please help me understand how to do this properly? For context, I am also using [Java Design Patterns](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/versionnumber/) website as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... that's the optimistic part. The optimism is that it *is* safe. If you have to be *certain* it's safe, then that's not optimistic.

The example you show definitely is susceptible to a race condition. Not only because of thread scheduling, but also due to transaction isolation level.

A simple read in MySQL, in the default transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE READ, will read the data that was committed at the time your transaction started.

Whereas updating data will act on the data that is committed at the time of the update. If some other concurrent session has updated the row in the database in the meantime, and committed it, then your update will "see" the latest committed row, not the row viewed by your get method.

The way to avoid the race condition is to not be optimistic. Instead, *force* exclusive access to the record. *[Doveryai, no proveryai.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust,_but_verify)*

If you only have one app instance, you might use a critical section for this.

If you have multiple app instances, critical sections cannot coordinate other instances, so you need to coordinate in the database. You can do this by using pessimistic locking. Either read the record using a [locking read query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), or else you can use [MySQL's user-defined locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. What is your thought on reading the version at time of retrieval and then at time of update just add the version number to the WHERE clause? For example the following pseudocode ```UPDATE table WHERE version = latestVersion```

Comment: It's optimistic. :-) What would you expect the code to do if the UPDATE reports that it affected zero rows? Meaning, the version must have changed since your get method initially read it.

Comment: Hm. I guess I don't really see the point of optimistic locking then. It almost seems like it just adds a "useless" expense for the version check even though it doesn't prevent conflicting updates.

Comment: Not for your usage pattern, but it is useful when you _don't_ need to keep client-side copies of data in sync with the corresponding data in the database. This is the fallacy of ORM usage patterns. They try to pretend that the client-side objects are like a facade for data in the database, but they aren't really.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean implementing some kind of safety on REST interface, please have a look at this article
https://sookocheff.com/post/api/optimistic-locking-in-a-rest-api/
What this article is not mentioning is posaibility to enforce conditional PUT/PATCH and even DELETE with HTTP 428 error code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/428

Your approach with relying on version seems to be legit to me.
Also, you'll need to handle some kind of optimistic locking exception and also convert it to 412 code.